# output information with a docker build

Tags: image, shell, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM centos:7 as builder
LABEL maintainer="seanchann <seanchann@test.com>"

COPY ./build.sh /build.sh
RUN source /build.sh; \
    build_lib ""
```

then in my `build_lib` function. it calls Makefile to build a c lib. but there not have any output information from the function of `build_lib`. how to enable output from `make` in `build_lib`

build.sh:

```
function build_lib(){
  cd /mysource/
  make
}
```

Comment: `cd /mysource/` that supposes mysource was COPYed first into the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to [`COPY build.sh`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) first into your image:

```
COPY build.sh /
```

Then you can try and run it.
Your docker build should be done in a dedicated folder where there is only your `Dockerfile` and `build.sh` script, in order to limit the `docker build` context volume.

Comment: so. this is a simple dockerfile. `build.sh` already exist. I mean `build.sh` has a lot of  output information when it call from shell! but in dockerfile , it nothing.

Comment: @seanchannzhou exactly: it needs to be copied first into the image.

Comment: copy it done. then how to enable the output informantion in `build.sh`

Comment: @seanchannzhou try adding an `echo "test"` at the beginning of your `function build_sh() {}` in `build.sh` (and docker build the image again): this is a test to see if the `echo` at least shows up.

Comment: yes, it work. but call `make` in `function build_sh(){}` nothing output

Comment: @seanchannzhou OK: next test: `echo "path to make: $(which make)"`: to check that make is available. And `pwd` to check in which path the function is called: are the sources of the c lib there as well (copied in the image)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the source present for build to run

`COPY mysource mysource/`

you should see `build.sh failed`  in your docker build output 
when make runs correctly you will see the make output run in `stdout`

if you want to catch this to a file use `tee`
e.g.

`docker build -t mycontainer . | tee output.file`